# How to alert on the Kubernetes Cluster health?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

We are running as hosted Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud (GKE) and scraping it with Prometheus.

My Question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39349744/kubernetes-prometheus-metrics-for-running-pods-and-nodes) one, but I'd like to know what are the most important metrics to look out for in the K8s Cluster and possibly alert on?

This is rather a K8s then a Prometheus question, but I'd really appreciate some hints. Please let me know if my question is to vague, so I can refine it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

etcd is the foundation of Kubernetes. So having a good set of alerts for it is important.
We wrote [this blog post](https://coreos.com/blog/developing-prometheus-alerts-for-etcd.html) and creating alerting rules for it and provided a base set at the end.

Further sources of important metrics in the Prometheus format are the Kubelet and cAdvisor, API servers, and  the fairly new [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics).
For those, I'm not aware of any public alerting rule sets as for etcd, unfortunately.

Generally, you want to ensure that the components as applications work flawlessly, e.g:

- Are my kubelets/API servers running/reachable? (`up` metric)
- Are their response latency and error rates within bounds?
- Can the API servers reach etcd?

Then there's the Kubernetes business logic aspect, e.g:

- Are there pods that have been in non-ready/crashloop state forever?
- Do I have enough CPU/memory capacity in my cluster?
- Are my deployment replica expectations fulfilled?

That's no drop-in solution unfortunately, but writing alerting rules roughly covering the scope of the above examples should get you quite far.